# Is it possible to create a database called C that is a view into all tables in database A + B?

Tags: sql-server, view

Using SQL 2005 or 2008, is it possible to create a database called C that is a view into all tables in database A + B ?   Databases A, B, and C  are on the same local server.

I am wanting to be able to create join queries between tables that are in 2 different databases.    Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create DatabaseC if you want to, but it adds no value. Just use 3 part object names:

```
SELECT 
   A.col1, B.col2
FROM
   DatabaseA.dbo.TableA A
   JOIN
   DatabaseB.dbo.TableB B ON A.xx = B.xx
```

Comment: What if this was an indexed view?  You could materialize it into database C if this fit some purpose?

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of that.  I just didn't realize it was possible.  It worked.  Thanks!

Comment: @TevoD - You can't `SCHEMABIND` to tables in other databases which is a requirement for indexed views.

Comment: @MartinSmith to add some color to that: SQL Server can't maintain indexed view consistency across databases because they could be restored, copied and they are not crash consistent as a unit.